# How to convert UTC + Offset Date to Local?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, timezone-offset

I have stored a value in an SQLServer DB in UTC which is `2016-07-28 16:00:00.000`:

[image]

I've converted that UTC DateTime string to an ISO string in Javascript then passed that value into a moment and called `toDate()` on it.

But the value output is still UTC including the offset.

So I stepped through the results of the two assignments and found the following values at each stage:

1st assignment: (UTC value 4:15 pm form DB converted to ISOString)

```
var isoDate = new Date('7/28/2016 4:15:00 PM').toISOString(); 

output value: "2016-07-28T15:15:00.000Z"
```

2nd assignment: (Being output as UTC plus offset instead of expected 17:15 local)

```
var localOutageStart = moment.utc(isoDate).toDate();

output value:  Thu Jul 28 2016 16:15:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Instead I'd like to output the value in local by using the offset, so it would output this value instead in local:

```
desired output value:  28 07 2016 17:15:00
```

How can I instead output the local moment time instead of UTC plus offset?
*I pass the result to a [Bootstrap datetime picker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) which I think takes a moment value.*

Comment: Your second example already is the local time, not the UTC time.  It would also help to know if you are looking for a string, a `Date` object, or a `moment` object in your results, and also what locale and time zone you are using.

Comment: `16:15` is already the local time. The UTC one is `15:15`. Why do you want to sum 1h again?

Comment: Also, the *input* in your first example is already in local time as well - so... what are you really trying to accomplish?  are you just looking for `.local()` on the moment object?  As in, `.utc().local().utc().local()`... you could do this all day long... :)

Comment: @Oriol 16:15 the first value is my UTC value read from the server side. So I'm expecting 17:15 in the local time. Instead it seems to be evaluating 15:15 as the UTC and adding the offset which is incorrect.

Comment: @BrianJ - That part (that the 16:15 is UTC) changes everything.  Your first operation treats it as if it were local time.

Comment: @MattJohnson the input in my first example (16:15) is the utc from my server. Local should be 17:15. It seems to be doing the reverse in my example taking the 16:15 subtracting the offset the converting back to UTC.

Comment: @MattJohnson ok my mistake so what operation should I call in the first assignment on the 16:15 UTC value? It seems converting to ISO is incorrect at that point? Also the final output should be a valid js Date or moment.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `2016-07-28 16:00:00.000` is in UTC, then you need to treat it as such.  As ISO8601, it should be  `2016-07-28T16:00:00.000Z`.  You can get this with moment like so:

```
var i = "2016-07-28 16:00:00.000";
var s = moment.utc(i).toISOString();
```

Or without moment, like so:

```
var i = "2016-07-28 16:00:00.000";
var s = new Date(i + " UTC").toISOString();  // yes, a non-standard hack, but works.
```

This creates the string: `"2016-07-28T16:00:00.000Z"`

Then when you want to use it on the client side:

```
var i = "2016-07-28T16:00:00.000Z";
var m = moment(i);  // here's a moment object you can use with your picker
var d = m.toDate(); // or, if you want a Date object

// or, if you want to custom format a string
var s = m.format("DD MM YYYY HH:mm:ss");
```

Or if you want to do this with the Date object alone:

```
var i = "2016-07-28T16:00:00.000Z";
var d = new Date(i);
```

(But custom formating is more difficult without moment)

Comment: +1 for the critical part of the browser receiving a string with no timezone, therefore being interpreted as being in the local timezone.

Comment: Nice I think the main cause of confusion here is what @kwah mentioned that the passed in server date string had no timezone specified.

Comment: I did notice one annoying thing when formatting the moment, it loses minute precision so for example if I read in an ISO string with a value of 4:10 PM after calling .format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM"); the minute value of the moment is subtracted by 3. I did post a question on here as haven't seen any similar issue raised before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679715/how-to-resolve-loss-of-minute-precision-formatting-a-moment-in-12hr

Comment: Format tokens are case sensitive.  You are using months (`MM`) where you should be using minutes (`mm`), and yes, it's been asked before.

Comment: @kwah—that is completely browser dependent and not to be relied upon.

Comment: @RobG - I _think_ you're agreeing with me that you should always include the timezone if you want consistent behaviour across browsers?

Comment: @kwah—nope. ;-) Parsing of strings using the Date constructor is problematic, hence [*this answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results/2587398#2587398).