# How to resolve loss of minute precision formatting a moment in 12HR?

Tags: javascript, formatting, momentjs, toisostring

I've converted an ISO date string to a momentjs moment and then formatted that moment using `.format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM")`.

When I output the final formatted moment, the minute value is incorrect as against the value read back from the iso string originally.

In this case the ISO string value holds 3:10 PM or "2016-08-03T03:10:00.000Z" as represented in the string. `But when I call format the moment value is 4:07PM meaning three minutes have been subtracted during the format.`

During debug I noted the following values at each assignment stage:

**Step 1** (converting the db value to an ISO string):

```
var actualBCR_Local = moment.utc('@Model.Escalation.Actual_BCR_ISO').toISOString();

value: "2016-08-03T03:10:00.000Z"
```

**Step 2** (converting the ISO string to a momentjs moment in order to represent the local time GMT+1):

```
 var actualBCR_Local_Moment = moment(actualBCR_Local);

 value: Wed Aug 03 2016 04:10:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

**Step 3** (formatting the moment in 12HR format for presentation, *issue is here as I lose 3 minutes as against the original value which should be 04:10*):

```
 var actualBCR_Local_Formatted = actualBCR_Local_Moment.format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM"); 

 value: "08/03/2016 04:08"
```

How can I prevent loss of minute precision when formatting a moment in 12HR format?

Answer (score 3):

that's because you use the wrong format

In this [section](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), you will find out that you are using `HH:MM` which means `hour:month`

If you use `HH:mm` then you will get correct time.

and that's why you got 2 minute loss, cause it display 08 as "month"

here is the what I tested

[image: example here]